# Generate List of Random Objects with Hypothesis

Tags: python, testing, python-hypothesis

I need to test a function in python that takes a list with any type of data, from integers to strings to any object a user makes up. Is there a way in hypothesis to generate a list with random objects? I know that I could generate a list of random floats with

```
@given(strategies.lists(strategies.floats()))
```

And so on and so forth with integers, chars, etc. But how can I make it so a random list has more than one data type with it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"[`hypothesis.strategies.one_of(*args)`](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html#hypothesis.strategies.one_of): Return a strategy which generates values from any of the argument strategies."

Will it work for you?